# Term for a vertex not part of any cycle in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What is the name for a vertex not being in any cycle of a directed graph?

Comment: I don't think there's any single word for that in wide use.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps say such a vertex is non-condensing, since a [condensation of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Definitions) will not combine it with other vertices.